# Package, missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, package

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, I keep getting the below error with this SQL query!?

SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (test_pkg.Fn_GetData('10'
     ,TO_DATE('01/04/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
     ,TO_DATE('30/04/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) AS result
);
```

Error message:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: TO_DATE, not TODATE, unless you've written your own function.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, thanks for that spot, still giving out about the right parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT test_pkg.Fn_GetData(
         '10',
         TO_DATE('01/04/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
         TO_DATE('30/04/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) AS result
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not know you can use a function as a table in Oracle, but the last parenthesis looks to be in the wrong place. It should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (test_pkg.Fn_GetData('10'
     ,TO_DATE('01/04/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
     ,TO_DATE('30/04/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))) AS result;
```

Although I don't see the point of "As result" in this query.